# How do I get a sectionNameKeyPath from a subset of a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to get a set of values from a one-to-many relationship for my section names. My fetchRequest entity is set to the single entity, and I would like to use (for example) @"to_many.attribute1" for the sectionNameKeyPath. However, I only want to use a certain subset of those to sort the entity.

Is there a way to add a predicate to the sectionNameKeyPath?

Or do I, as I'm afraid I might, need to recreate my data model so that data is easier to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option I've used when my sectionNameKeyPath needs to reference something that is non-trivial is to add a new attribute to my model and mark it as Transient.

Then you can add a category to the managed object which has a getter that calculates the field based on your rules.

```
@implementation MyObject (SectionKeyPathAdditions)

-(NSDate *)toManyAttribute1Date // This is the new transient attribute name
{
     NSDate *dynamicReturnDate = [NSDate date];
     // use app logic to grab the subset of valid dates from attribute1
     return dynamicReturnDate;
}
```

Comment: That sounds promising! Thank you!

Comment: While this will work, it can be resource intensive for large amounts of data. Transient methods require that an object be instantiated before the transient value can be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate would be something like:

```
ALL to_many.attribute1=="something"
```

The ALL and ANY operators search sets which is what a to-many relationship returns. Although, you can't daisy chain them e.g.

```
ALL to_many.another_to_many.attribute1
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to know specifically if you can add a predicate to the sectionNameKeyPath.

Comment: If you mean the sectionNameKeyPath of a NSFetchedResultsRequest, then no. If you want to alter the default section name behavior you have to subclass NSFetchedResultsRequest.